# Storing Values into an Array of Pointers to Structs

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I am trying to figure out how to store values from an input file into an array of pointers to structs. The input file looks like this (first is the name in the struct and the following numbers are to be stored into the array of integers within the struct). The print statements in between are to help me see where the program fails.

MY CODE:

```
typedef struct{
  char name[10];
  int songs[10];
}Customer;

Customer *memory_locations[100];

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  FILE *fp_data = fopen(argv[1], "r"); //file with tree structure
  FILE *fp_query = fopen(argv[2], "r"); //file with commands


  int index = 0;
  char targetCust[10];
  char buffer;

  fscanf(fp_data, "%s\n", targetCust);

  while(!feof(fp_data)){
    printf("1%d", index);
    memory_locations[index] = (Customer *)malloc(sizeof(Customer));
    printf("2%d", index);
    fscanf(fp_data, "%s" , memory_locations[index]->name);
    printf("3%d", index);
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
      fscanf(fp_data, " %d", memory_locations[index]->songs[i]);
      printf("4%d", index);
    }
    printf("5%d", index);
    index++;
  }

  printf("%d %s", index, targetCust);
  
}
```

INPUT FILE:

```
Alice
Alice 4 2 0 2 0 0 5 3 3 2
Bob   0 0 1 2 0 3 5 1 1 5
Carol 0 2 0 0 2 1 0 1 1 2
David 2 2 0 2 1 2 3 1 3 0
Emily 0 4 0 2 5 5 4 3 0 3
```

The output returns 102030 and then a segmentation fault so the problem is reading the integers from the input file. Is the target location from the fscanf() wrong since it's an array of pointers to structs? That's the only thing I can think of yet do not know how to do it correctly.

Comment: while printing can be an indicator I would suggest trying to use a debugger since it can be a lot more informative, and another tool that might be efficient in this type of scenario can be valgrind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the target location from the fscanf() wrong since it's an array of pointers to structs?

No, fscanf is wrong because there is a small typo in the program. `fscanf` need pointers in parameters. The rest of the code seems OK.

```
fscanf(fp_data, " %d",  memory_locations[index]->songs[i]); // Segfault
fscanf(fp_data, " %d", &memory_locations[index]->songs[i]); // Correct
                       ^
```

For `name`, there is no problem because `memory_locations[index]->name` correspond to the address of the beginning of the table.